# VPN install enforces screen lock

Tags: settings, lock-screens, vpn

I was trying to install a VPN on my phone and somehow I added a screen lock. I cannot turn it off now. When I go to lock screen, select screen lock, enter my pin and next it takes me to the screen select screen lock. I should be able to tap on 'None' to deactivate the screen lock, but its greyed out and I can't tap it. Any ideas, its driving me crazy. I'm using a Lg Optimus l5 (lg-e612).

Comment: VPN enforces a screen lock, that's an absolutely normal security precaution. Otherwise anybody getting hold of your device could easily break in into the network behind.

Comment: A precaution that makes sense. But anyway I can understand that users want to have control if the lock screen is enabled or not, given that their device is not [affected by a adminstrative policy](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1056433))